# issue automating with Ruby

Tags: ruby, automation, watir

I am a beginer with Ruby and I have some issue using Ruby and Watir  to automate tests. My problem is I cant reach text field in web page with
‘id= namecolumnbeginswith’ and ‘name=ProjectsList_namecolumnbeginswith_0’

i tried this :

```
ie.text_field(:name, "ProjectsList_namecolumnbeginswith_0").set("gapc")
```

then

```
ie.hidden(:xpath, "//input[ @id='namecolumnbeginswith' @title='Search By Name'  @name='ProjectsList_namecolumnbeginswith_0' @iniValue='Starts With' @prompt='Starts With' @value='Starts With']/").set("gapc")
```

then

```
ie.frame(:name, "FRAME").frame(:name, "nested_frame").text_field(:name, "ProjectsList_namecolumnbeginswith_0").set("gapc")
```

then

```
ie.link(:href, "/pwcollab/wdk/theme/documentum/css/dragdrop.css").click
```

then

```
ie.link(:class, "projectsList").click
```

then

```
ie.frame(:name,"FRAME").frame(:name,"nested_frame").button(:value,"ProjectsList_OK_0").click
```

no one of all this commands works

This web page is referenced by :

```
    '</script>'
</head>
<frameset onload="onLoad()" rows="100%,*" border="0">
    <frame title="Frame for system use" src="/pwcollab/wdk/blank.htm" noresize />
    <frame title="Frame for system use" src="/pwcollab/wdk/blank.htm" />
</frameset>
</html>
```

I use watir to find my frames and got this result with IRB :

```
irb(main):048:0> ie.show_frames
```

there are 0 frames

```
=> 0..-1
```

Then I tried to DOM to access to the text field using

Ie.div(:class)trying all classes  I always have this error

```
Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException: Unable to locate element
```

To summarize I need some advices to access a text field in a web page using Ruby & Watir to automate web application test.

Comment: almost impossible to tell where you might be going wrong without seeing the page itself, or at least the relevant HTML (where the input field is defined at the very least) of the page.

Comment: The other useful thing is to get the error messages you are seeing specific to the things you have tried, as this often provides a lot more clues as to what the problem is than 'no one of all this commands works' which basically tells us nothing

Comment: Downticked due to lack of response from user.  They were last seen 22 days ago and apparently have little interest in working with us to solve their issue.

Answer (score 0):

We need more information to be able to tell you where the problem might be (aside from a loose nut behind the keyboard ;-)   Myself and other watir users would be glad to offer assistance but without your responding to the comments (edit the question) there's not enough for us to work from.

Specifically in order to tell you what might be wrong we would need at the very least one of two things.

1) web page 'source' code where the element you are trying to interact with is defined.  None of the page elements you are trying to interact with are present in the small bit of HTML that you included.  Not even the frame you try to use 'nested frame' appears in there, so unfortunately that little bit of HTML is completely utterly useless when it comes to giving us the info we need to assist you.

2) Specific errors.  *"no one of all this commands works"* communicates zero useful information.  If we can see the specific error that is being returned from the various things you have tried, then we have a little more insight into exactly HOW and WHY something is not working, and knowing the underlying cause of the error might potentially be able to tell you what you need to do to get your code working.

Lastly just a bit of advice, You give an ID value for one of the elements you are trying to address.  If an item has an ID, since by HTML standards ID's are supposed to be unique within the page, that alone should suffice to identify the element. Adding in class, name or any other attribute would be redundant at that point.